# Code overriding and multitenancy with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, multi-tenant

I am about to build a [multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) application with Ruby On Rails. Each client will have its own personalized configuration through a YAML file (or eventually something stored in the database, whatever works). Given the sale process and the amount of configuration needed for each client, the dev team will be building the configuration files. The expected number of clients is less than 100.

How do you override code (controllers, views, layouts) for specific clients (ie : one module per client?) How can this be done within rails?

Comment: have you considered giving each client its own app and database? that would be easy to deploy and scale (on a per-client basis) on heroku

Comment: @Seamus Asbhere I am not really concerned with scale for this specific application. With the target market, there's no way we will have a scale problem. And even if we did, we could partition the database easily. For the splitting the codebase, I think that would be too had to maintain, don't you think?

Comment: you could run everybody off separate deploys of a master branch until any one client needed a customization. you would create a branch for that client. then you could periodically merge master back into each customized branch. that seems more solid than putting multiple client customizations inside the models, controllers, views, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can have modules for each customer and inside your controllers you can dynamically require corresponding module. Assuming you have current_user instance, in ApplicationCOntroller you can have before_filter that loads up an instance variable @client_module and that variable can be used inside of your controllers to extend your controller. YOu will probably want to do one module per client per controller to make life easier

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this with routes?

```
    get ":client/:controller/:action/:id"
```

Study [routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to get some ideas for resources and namespaces.